Hartree approximation for interactions higher than $φ^4$
In relation to this original post: Black magic "Hartree" approximation , how would one go about reducing terms like $φ^6$ or $φ^8$, to quadratic ones, for example. I have been stuck trying to produce the correct result for $φ^6$ for some time and so far i have gotten this result:
\begin{equation}
\phi^6 \rightarrow 15 \langle \phi^2 \rangle^2 \phi^2 + 15 \langle \phi^2 \rangle \phi^4 - 5 \langle \phi^2 \rangle^3
\end{equation}
which doesn't seem to produce the correct mean value for $φ^6$, which would be $\langle \phi^6 \rangle=15\langle \phi^2 \rangle^3$. I have assumed that $\langle \phi \rangle=0$.

It would greatly help if you posted the steps you did to arrive at your result, since then we could identify where exactly you have made a mistake. So far, all we can say is that your result is wrong, and you already know that.

This is just the wick theorem. Or equivalently: Mean field approximation ~ non correlation ~ gaussian average. In the case of gaussian variable your last result is just wick theorem
